# Call function associative variables

Tags: php, oop, frameworks, functional-programming

i want to ask if it's possible to call Class methods in PHP by passing an associative array to a method and then name the function signature arguments with array indexes.
I tried this:

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller,$method), array("id" => 1));
```

it works but it's positional.

```
 public function do($id,$test) {
        echo $id; // output 1
        echo $test; // null
}
```

There's a way to make $id exactly "id" index from the array? so you can mix the function arguments without loosing  the correct value?

Comment: AFAIK no, the parameters array should go just like as you would call the method normally, func(par1, par2, par3...).

Comment: This is possible with reflection, but you wouldn't be able to specify parameters in a any arbitrary order unless all arguments had default values.